# How do you write ordered multi-inserts wih CTEs?

Tags: postgresql, insert, cte

With the [table like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5f43cee06b406a523b5280a6523d21d4):

```
CREATE TABLE test_1 (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE test_2 (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE test_refs (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  id_1 bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES test_1,
  id_2 bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES test_2
);
```

And the insert query like this:

```
WITH new_test_1_rows AS (
  INSERT INTO test_1
  DEFAULT VALUES
  RETURNING *
), new_test_2_rows AS (
  INSERT INTO test_2
  DEFAULT VALUES
  RETURNING *
), test_row_pairs AS (
  INSERT INTO test_refs
   ( id_1, id_2 )
  VALUES
    (
      (SELECT id FROM new_test_1_rows),
      (SELECT id FROM new_test_1_rows)
    )
  RETURNING *
)
SELECT *
FROM test_row_pairs
```

Basically what it does:

- inserts a row into `test_1`
- inserts a row into `test_2`
- inserts their IDs pair into `test_refs`

The problem is I would like to rewrite the query into a multi-insert query, i.e. for the `n` rows inserted into `test_1` insert the `n` rows into `test_2` and then create the `n` rows in `test_refs` for the inserted values. For that I need to know the row index within the CTE, so it could be used as a join key. Is it something you can do within the `RETURNING` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... for the `n` rows inserted into `test_1` insert the n rows into `test_2`
> and then create the `n` rows in `test_refs` for the inserted values. For
> that I need to know the row index within the CTE, so it could be used
> as a join key. Is it something you can do within the `RETURNING`
> clause?

There is **no provision** to add row numbers in the `RETURNING` clause - no equivalent for `WITH ORDINALITY` that can be used with set-returning functions. See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/939860)

And if you add a window function (like you may have tried), you get:

> ```
> ERROR:  window functions are not allowed in RETURNING
> ```

The Postgres-specific `ROWS FROM` syntax can return rows in lock-step but that, too, is for set-returning functions only. See:

- [Unnest multiple arrays in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27854382/939860)

You must take the **long way** home and generate row numbers in another CTE or subquery. Example with two rows:

```
WITH new_test_1_rows AS (
   INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT)
   RETURNING *
   )
, new_test_2_rows AS (
   INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (DEFAULT), (DEFAULT)
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO test_refs (id_1, id_2)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id
FROM  (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn, id  -- !
   FROM new_test_1_rows
   ) t1
JOIN  (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn, id  -- !
   FROM new_test_2_rows
   ) t2 USING (rn)  -- !
RETURNING *
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=54e7e9c59ce84b3dcb479b1010e77d03)*